# Why am I getting a StackOverflowException here?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

My class is like

```
public static class Duplication
{
    public const int Size = 1024;

    public static byte[] Bits
    {   get
        {
            if(Bits == null)
                SetBits();
            return Bits;
        }
        private set
        {
            Bits = value;
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

and I'm getting a `StackOverflowException` on the `get`ter when I run

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SizeCheck()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(Duplication.Size, Duplication.Bits.Length);
    }
```

Can someone explain why that might be? Seems like a weird exception as I can't think of anything that is blowing up the call stack.

Comment: Your entire property is incorrect, you need a backing field. The immediate problem is that the getter of `Bits` calls the getter of `Bits`, but the setter has the same problem. Introduce a backing field and use that inside the property.

Answer (score 14):

Because you are calling the getter method or `Bits` inside of the `get` method here:

```
if(Bits == null)
```

You need to declare a field explicitly in order to use your property:

```
private static byte[] _bits;

public static byte[] Bits
{   get
    {
        if(_bits == null)
            SetBits();
        return _bits;
    }
    private set
    {
        _bits = value;
    }
}
```

Also a side note the `if` statement can be shortened to:

```
return _bits ?? (_bits = SetBits());
```